# How to find the exact spectrum of the squeezed-driven Kerr-nonlinear model?

Tags: quantum-optics, eigenvalue

#### Model

The Hamiltonian considered is$$H=P({a^{\dagger}}^2+a^2)-K{a^{\dagger}}^2a^2,$$where $a$ is the bosonic annihilation operator $[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$.

#### Ground state

By rewriting $H$ as $$H=-K({a^{\dagger}}^2-\beta^2)(a^2-\beta^2)+K\beta^4,\ \beta=\sqrt{P/K},$$
the ground state can be shown to be the coherent $|\pm\beta\rangle$, which is two-fold degenerated with eigenvalue $K\beta^4$.

#### Excited state

The eigenspectrum of excited state can be approximated obtained in the strong driven limit $P\gg K$. To show this, rewirting $H$ in the displacement frame$$H'=D(\pm\beta)HD^{\dagger}(\pm\beta)=-4K\beta^2a^{\dagger}a-K{a^{\dagger}}^2a^2\mp2K\beta({a^{\dagger}}^2a+h.c.)+K\beta^4$$with the displacement transformation $D(\pm\beta)=\exp(\pm\beta a^{\dagger}\mp\beta a)$. In the limit $P\gg K$, $\beta^2\gg \beta^0,\beta^1$, and hence, $H'$ is well approximated by a harmonic oscillator $H'=-4K\beta^2a^{\dagger}a$ with eigenstates $|n\rangle$. Back to the origin frame $H$, it's excited states are nearly
two-fold degenerated since the two states $D(\pm\beta)|n\rangle$ is quasi-orthogonal $$\langle n|D^{\dagger}(-\beta)D(\beta)|n\rangle=f(\beta^2)e^{-2\beta^2}\approx0$$
and have the same energy $-4nK\beta^2+K\beta^4$ in the limit $P\gg K$.

#### Questions

The discussion about the excited states spectrum only valids in the strong driven limit. Can   anybody help me to find the exact spectrum of $H$ of whatever the values of $P,K$ taken?

Comment: One could try to write down the stationary Schrödinger equation and solve it for eigenstates and eigenvalues.